# Flammability of Silicone Sealants with Electronics

Tags: electricity, environmental-sealing, hazardous-areas

I'm aware that electronics grade silicone rubbers exist but I've also read in a particular [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/32798/can-silicone-sealant-be-used-to-insulate-and-waterproof-electronic-components) on here that common silicone rubber sealants can also be used for electronics, providing that they're neutral cured and not acid cured.

I'm working on a project where I'd love to use a common silicone rubber sealant as a) I have an abundance of it and b) if what I have is not appropriate there's many hardware stores close to me, but all the SR products that I have and whats available at the hardware stores list that they are flammable and to keep away from sources of ignition.

Is there a reason flammability wasn't mentioned in the above post? Am I overestimating the ignition potential of an electronic circuit?

Comment: Re-read the comments in the post you link to. Flammability *IS* mentioned by @sharptooth.

Comment: Right you are @LorenzoDonati. Do you have anything to add RE the risk of ignition of silicone rubber sealants?

Comment: @Seano You could try setting fire to some of it outdoors away from anything else that could catch fire (a) when it is still wet and (b) when it has cured and the flammable solvent and curing by-products have gone away.