# How can I isolate properly a home made PCB?

Tags: pcb

N.B: I'm still a 14 years old boy that is just a beginner in electrical engineering.

I've just finished My first Successful **Single** Sided PCB Project, which was a Relay controlled wirelessly via an infrared remote, so a part of the PCB must handle a **220Vac**.I made the traces which carry 220vac so thick so that it can carry high current and voltage.

My main Problem is that I want to isolate the copper side of the PCB to avoid electrical shock and short circuit but I don't know what is the substances I can use and How ?

And don't forget that these traces can become hot alittle bit.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what your question is asking, but a good way to isolate the circuit board from a user is to put it in an insulating box (the circuit, not the user).

Comment: @Andrew Morton And what is the material of the isolating box ?

Comment: Typically it would be ABS; there are some examples [here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=plastic+project+boxes+for+electronics&t=h_&iax=images&ia=images).

Comment: @ Shams The electrical resistance of standard PCB foil (1 ounce per square foot) is 0.000500 ohms per square. Understanding why ANY SIZE SQUARE applies is a fun exercise, a bit of drawing and thinking. And the thermal resistance of a square of that same copper foil is 70 watts/ degree C, the heat flowing only in one edge and out the opposite edge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great to be doing stuff like that at this age!

I think the previous answer did not address the question which was how to insulate PCB trace.

If you circuit runs 220V you probably want to put it inside a plastic box.

You can also insulate it by putting coating the trace with resin like epoxy or you can put the whole circuit inside silicone

[There are also some spray to do so](https://www.all-spec.com/Catalog/Soldering-Rework/Soldering-Chemicals/Conformal-Coatings/8695-95?gclid=CjwKCAjwlejcBRAdEiwAAbj6KRJzGsGBxqNsoMv16j5RAmmtsRzAzo7QqWY0RPGrXdHXpVEdXNu00hoCtk8QAvD_BwE)

[image: pcb covered with silicone].

Comment: Since you mention silicone, it may be a good idea to link that [other answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/32812/107479), which gives details about which kind of silicone is appropriate.

Answer (score 7):

*N.B: I'm still a 14 years old boy that is just a beginner in electrical engineering.*

Excellent! Get a head-start by starting electronics at a young age :-) I did the same and never regretted it.

Indeed for high **current** you want the traces to be **wide**

For high **voltage** you want the **distance between traces to be large**

*And don't forget that these traces can become hot alittle bit.*

If that happens then you might need thicker traces. If that's not possible a way around that is to make the copper traces thicker using ordinary solder. That will only work if there's no **soldermask** on those traces. If there already is soldermask, you could carefully scrape it away (don't damage the copper!).

How wide should your tracks be for a certain current? It depends on the current, copper thickness and how much temperature rise you allow. Yeah, not easy, there's a [calculator here](https://www.digikey.nl/en/resources/conversion-calculators/conversion-calculator-pcb-trace-width).

How large must the spacing between the tracks be? There are calculators for that, [here is an example](https://www.smps.us/pcbtracespacing.html).

For 220 V AC you generally need about 1 cm of distance between the mains connected side and the "safe to touch" side. Ideally there would be a slot (a hole in the PCB) in between.

What you could also do is look for similar PCBs, that can even be old PCBs from discarded equipment like a microwave, PC power supply or a TV. Look at those PCBs to get a feeling for how it is done.

Last tip, if you do not know the [EEVBlog](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC2DjFE7Xf11URZqWBigcVOQ) yet then you should have a look. There are several videos regarding circuit and PCB design.

Comment: Bimpelrekkie, I appreciate your answer very much and I learned alot of your answer but Damien answer is what I need. sorry but I still learn English and I used incorrect word which is isolate instead if insulate.forgive me from my fault please.